# Power Automate Desktop Flow TImeout

Tags: power-automate, power-platform, power-automate-desktop

I have a set of power automate desktop flows and I trigger them from cloud. I want to put a timeout for my flows to avoid infinite wait which may occurs because of various reasons including UIS load issues. So I want to put a maximum time for the execution if it exceeds the maximum time I need to make the flow fail/cancel it's own.

In simple words I need a timeout for the Desktop Flow.

I know I can configure timeout in the cloud action in which I call power automate desktop but it counts the time which the flows is in queue. I dont want to consider the queue time for this timeout.